# Solve $y'(t) = \dfrac{1}{1+ty}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does the following reasoning make sense?
\begin{gather}
\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{1+ty},\\
1+ty \; dy = dt, \\
\int1+ty \;dy = \int dt,\\
y+t\dfrac{y^2}{2} = t+C.
\end{gather}

Comment: No, you didn't separate the variables properly. There shouldn't be $t$ on the left and $y$ on the right before integration.

Comment: i suggest to define a new function $ u(t)=ty(t) $ to see what happens

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bxy%7D

Answer (score 3):

This equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{dt}{dy}=1+ty\\\frac{dt}{dy}-yt=1$$ which is linear with factor $e^{\int (-y)dy}=e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}$ and so
$$t=e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}\left\{\int e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\cdot1dy+c\right\}$$
Then use Gamma function to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that $\int t y dy$ integral like that. Try deriving an equation for $t(y)$ and solving it using an integrating factor.